# scipy loadmat support for extended ASCII characters

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I need to read Matlab files that may contain extended ASCII characters.

Example in site name
[Actual characters entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54CF5.png)

scipy loadmat does not seem to be able to load files with extended ASCII characters. I can load the Matlab file in Octave and it simply replaces the unrecognized character with a ?, but it won't load using loadmat. Is there a way to get loadmat to recognize or just ignore those characters? I don't have control over how the Matlab file is created and the offending character(s) are not typically important to my code.

Octave example
[Octave example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WkB7.png)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was a misconfigured Matlab file that the creator has now fixed. However, better error messages when loadmat crashes would be nice.